# Describe your approach of keys/secrets versioning using Terraform and Hashi Vault

Tags: terraform

I use Terraform and Hashi Vault for storing secrets.

I refer to the application code version in the infrastructure code. Which means that I always can restore the required version of the whole infrastructure (roll back to a previous git tag, terraform apply). But I had a hard time trying to link secrets versions to the code.

Example, if I have the infrastructure code version 2.3.4  (i.e. Terraform module version) I can specify that this version has to use 1.2.3 version of the code. Let's imagine that this version has to use version 1 of secrets. 
A developer has to add a new env variable, so the code version will be 1.2.4 and we have to add a new secret to the Hashi Vault.

So, there is no problem to add a new secret to the Hashi Vault and this means that the secrets version becomes 2.

So, the problem is how to link 3 of these versions together, i.e. the app version, the infrastructure version, and the secrets version in Terraform?

For example, how can I know that version of the app 1.2.4 is compatible with secrets version 2 and infrastructure version 2.3.4 in my case?

I know that the question is a bit tricky, but you might have some pieces of advice.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for but normally the application version is managed by Git. What version of your secrets to use depends on your application code. So you can add the version to the path of the secret /app/version/secret or /app/secret/version. The terraform api always returns the latest version - that is why I recommend this hack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since Terraform doesn't support Hashi Vault versioning, I can just add the version to the secret path (appname/version/secrets), which means that I have to copy all my secrets each time I create a new secrets version, so in a few years, I will  end up with tons of folders, that is why I don't like this approach.
I even thought to create some wrapper, like custom scripts to read keys versioning from the Vault.
So, I just want to know if someone has any better ideas to manage secrets and use their versions in Terraform.

Comment: I think that what your are looking for is similar to the concept of database migrations but hashicorp does not provide that: https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/secrets-management/sm-versioned-kv.

Comment: One way would be to keep your secrets in file on a an encrypted bucket, versioned. and you remove all your secrets and recreate them according to application version deployed. Or you can implement your own secrets migration utility.